# How to get variable from string delphi 7

Tags: variables, delphi-7

```pascal
unit Test;

interface

var number: Integer;
    num1, num2: string;

implementation
begin
  number:=1;
  if number=1 then begin
    num+number:='value 1';
  end
  else if number=2 then begin
    num+number:='value 2';
  end;

  showmessage(num+number,''); 
end.
```

I want to show this result "value 1" if `number = 1` and "value 2" if `number = 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array, as the numbers are sequential, eg:

```
unit Test;

interface

var
  number: Integer;
  num: array[1..2] of string;

implementation

begin
  number := 1;
  if number = 1 then begin
    num[number] := 'value 1';
  end
  else if number=2 then begin
    num[number] := 'value 2';
  end;

  ShowMessage(num[number]); 
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

use Format

```
var number: integer;
value: string;
begin
  value := format('value %d', [number]);
end;
```

it will give "Value (n)" as in "value 1" if you put 1 in the variabel